Displaying percentage of audio tags loaded cross-browser, with accuracy so that controls are unavailable until everything loads
I have a bunch of audio tags in child iframe that look like this :


<audio id='n0' preload='auto' onCanPlay='CountASampleAsLoaded();'><source src='Sounds/0.mp3' type='audio/mp3'></audio>



then this JavaScript function in the child script :


    // Increments the samples loaded percentage during page load, until it reaches 100%, then hides the loading message and shows Options & Display
function CountASampleAsLoaded() {
PreviewTag = parent.document.getElementById('LoadingPercentageHolder');
var LastLoaded = parseFloat(PreviewTag.innerHTML);
var CurrentlyLoaded = (LastLoaded + (100 / parent.window.InstrumentsLastSampleRanks['<?php echo $_POST['Instrument']; ?>'])).toFixed(3);
    if (CurrentlyLoaded > 100) {
    CurrentlyLoaded = 100;
    Fade(parent.document.getElementById('LoadingDiv'));
    Fade(parent.document.getElementById('OptionsMenu'),'In');
    }
PreviewTag.innerHTML = CurrentlyLoaded;
}



and this html in the parent script :


    <!-- Loading Message displayed while the sounds load -->
<div id='LoadingDiv' class='OrangeGradientGrayText ' style='position:absolute; left:15pt; top:15pt; width:700pt; font-size:28pt;
opacity:1'>
    <span id='LoadingPercentageHolder'>
    0</span>% of <span id='InstrumentNameHolder'>Bowed</span>&nbsp;<span id='AudioFormatHolder'>.mp3</span>'s loaded...
</div>



It only works okay in FireFox, where all sounds are actually loaded once the LoadingDiv has displayed 100% and vanished to leave place to the Options Div...
In Chrome, Edge & Opera, the percentage increments normally a little time, then it boosts to 100% immediately, but the sounds of the higher notes on the Keyboard are not yet loaded : they do not play when pressed.
I tried to use onCanPlayThrough, and suprisingly it was even less reliable : even FireFox would display 100% and get notes that don't play after...
I then came up with an ultimate work around : setting the audio tags volume to 0 onPlay, give them the "autoplay" attribute, and put CountASampleAsLoaded onEnded, the whole thing with a boolean that turns true once the page is loaded, and nested in the onPlay event handler (if (!PageLoaded) {AudtioTag.volume = 0;} and the CountASampleAsLoaded function. so the function isn't executed each time you play a note once the page has loaded... It ended up in scope problems and the volume being set to 0 even after load so no sounds would come out of the notes. (volume was supposed to be toggled back to 1 in CountASampleAsLoaded; whatever...)
Any idea of a work-around that would be accurate?
You can see the code in action at :
https://www.chord-book.com/HexKeyboard/HexKeyboard.php (this is the demo version which I update only to the last unbugged version)

Here you assign a text (toFixed()) to var CurrentlyLoaded.
var CurrentlyLoaded = (LastLoaded + (100 / parent.window.InstrumentsLastSampleRanks['<?php echo $_POST['Instrument']; ?>'])).toFixed(3);

And here you want to make an numeric comparison with the text:
if (CurrentlyLoaded > 100) {

That don't work. Remove toFixed(3) in the first part and use it when formatting output;
PreviewTag.innerHTML = CurrentlyLoaded.toFixed(3);

